# Как в go правильно проверить переменую на nil?

Tags: golang

Пишем код на Go 1.5

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyInterface interface {
    GeyValue() string
}

type MyValue struct {}

func (myValue MyValue) GeyValue() string {
    return "My Value"
}

func Generate() *MyValue {
    return nil
}

func Test() MyInterface {
    myValue := Generate()
    return myValue
}

func main() {
    myValue := Test()

    if myValue == nil {
        fmt.Println("No value")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", myValue.GeyValue())
    } 
}
```

Здесь я ожидаю получить вывод:

> No value

Но получаю:

> panic: value method main.MyValue.GeyValue called using nil *MyValue pointer
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>   main.(*MyValue).GeyValue(0x0, 0x4f21c0, 0x5d0a88)
>             <autogenerated>:1 +0x85
>   main.main()
>            C:/Golang/src/MyLabs/Lab001/lab001.go:30 +0x18a
>   exit status 2

Вопрос. Как правильно написать метод main, чтобы проверить `myValue` на nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерфейсы в Go - это такие структуры, в которых лежит указатель на объект и его тип.

По этому переменная-интерфейс равна `nil` только когда и указатель на объект и тип пустые. Если тип не пустой, то переменная-интерфейс не равна `nil`, что мы и видим в коде - в `Test()` переменная `myValue` преобразуется в интерфейс, и в эту переменную-интерфейс кладется тип `*MyValue`, и его значение равное `nil`.

#### Как проверить интерфейс на `nil`

Официальный ответ - [не надо этого делать](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/wnH302gBa4I) <s>потому что так делают только в неправильном коде который пишут неправильные разработчики, а язык на самом деле хороший</s>.

Нормальный ответ:

- если известен тип, то надо сделать каст:
  `myValuePtr, ok := myValue.(*MyValue); ok && myValuePtr == nil`
- если тип неизвестен, то надо использовать `reflect`:
  `reflect.ValueOf(myValue).IsNil()`

Comment: Ваше утверждение идет в разрез практики Dependency Injection. Т.е. по вашему все, кто её применяет неправильные разработчики.

Comment: тогда "так делают только в неправильном коде который пишут неправильные разработчики, а язык на самом деле хороший" лучше оформить, как цитату. А то это выглядит, как ваше утверждение.